# What is the intended usage pattern for the AppFabric Cache GetAndLock(forceLock = true) method signature?

Tags: .net, appfabric-cache

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff424962.aspx) states:

> If forceLock is true, key is locked irrespective of key-value pair
>   presence in cache.

With no further explanation, e.g. what it means to have a lock on a key that is not in the cache and what the intended technique is (or are) for inserting a cache item within the lock.

Answer (score 1):

From my past experiences, it is used to reserve a key in the cache by a client.

As you may know, Lock methods are suitable for Resource Data : Shared Memory, concurrently read and written into, accessed by a large number of transactions, such as auction items.

If the key does not exist you can lock the key if it's the first thread/client in and have other threads spin and wait until DataCacheErrorCode.ObjectLocked error code goes away.

Answer (score 0):

this is what intended for appfabric pattern.

```
this.Cache.GetAndLock<ICollection<string>>(key, new TimeSpan(0, 0, 30)
```

you can use generic parameters for fetching the cache item.